# How to use object of one class in the method of another class?

Tags: python, oop, methods, constructor

I'm very new to Python and OOP in general. I found a problem that requires me to make 2 classes use the objects created from one class as the argument of the other. The problem states that I have to make the classes, constructors and methods without changing the given code to get the sample output.
My code:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.__x=x      #private variable
    def method(self,y):
        self.__y=y      #private variable
    def details(self):
        print(f'x = {self.__x}') #private variable
        print(self.__y)
class A:
    def __init__(self,z):
        self.z=z
#==================================
#This can't be changed.
obj1=A('a')
obj2=A('b')
obj3=B('x')
obj3.method(obj1)
obj3.method(obj2)
obj3.details()
```

but this gives me the memory address of the objects obj1 and obj2 instead of the values a and b. I also tried to take an empty string and then concatinate a and b to it but the object type cant be concatinated with str. So, I'm basically stuck now. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

The sample output is:

```
x = x
a
b
```

Comment: It doesn't give you "the memory address", that is the *default string representation of any object*. Why do you *expect* it to print anything else?

Comment: As an aside, `self.__x = x` **is not private**. Python *doesn't have private variables*. To signal that a variable is not part of the public API, use a *single underscore*. Double-underscores are for name-mangling, which is not the same thing as private

Comment: my question is how to get the method to take the object as the parameter. I can feel that the main mistakes I made are in the method and printing the values obtained from method.

Comment: That's exactly what it is doing already. The method takes the object as a parameter and assigns it to `self.__y`. Why do you think that isn't working? The problem is what you are printing.

Comment: so my print statement needs to be changed? How can I print the assigned value instead of something like this
```<__main__.A object at 0x016DC3D0>```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `print(self.__y)` You need to do `print(self.__y.z)` to get to the value that object is storing in `z`.

But to get that sample output, you have to keep track of all of the objects ever passed into the `obj3.method` method, and not just the last one. What I mean is that `self.__y` needs to be a list.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.__x=x      #private variable
        self.__y=[]
    def method(self,y):
        self.__y.append(y)      #private variable
    def details(self):
        print(f'x = {self.__x}') #private variable
        for obj in self.__y:
            print(obj.z)
class A:
    def __init__(self,z):
        self.z=z
#==================================
#This can't be changed.
obj1=A('a')
obj2=A('b')
obj3=B('x')
obj3.method(obj1)
obj3.method(obj2)
obj3.details()
```

Since these objects don't actually represent anything, it makes naming things difficult, and I think that makes the entire problem more difficult to understand, but below is how I would name the variables that you do have control over. And as the comments have already mentioned there isn't really a concept of private variables in Python, but we typically put a single underscore in front of variables if you want to warn people that a variable should be treated like a private variable.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.obj_A_list = []

    def method(self, obj_a):
        self.obj_A_list.append(obj_a)

    def details(self):
        print(f'x = {self.prop}')
        for obj in self.obj_A_list:
            print(obj.prop)

class A:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

#==================================
#This can't be changed.
obj1=A('a')
obj2=A('b')
obj3=B('x')
obj3.method(obj1)
obj3.method(obj2)
obj3.details()
```